# Sharp flat panel scaling with Nvidia drivers

Tags: resolution

I have a Samsung 226BW flat panel with a 1680x1050 native resolution. As my PC is rather dated (Athlon XP 2600+ and GeForce 6600 GT), I need to run more recent games (but still old) on a lower resolution. Unfortunately, scaling low resolutions to 1680x1050 results in a very blurry image (bilinear scaling).

I have created a custom resolution of 840x525 in the Nvidia control panel. Technically, this resolutions allows perfect upscaling to 1680x1050 without the need for bilinear interpolation. Unfortunately, the Nvidia driver always seems to do bilinear scaling, again resulting in a blurry image.

However, I seem to remember that I did obtain crisp images using this resolution in the past (before a Windows re-install). Maybe only some driver versions support integer upscaling without bilinear filtering? Or perhaps there are other solutions?

Comment: You would actually see a sharper image just using nearest-neighbour scaling, since it would effectively "double" each pixel rather then creating a blurred intermediate pixel in-between.  You might have been using an older driver which did that.

Comment: Obvously. But I don't want start installing every driver release supporting the 6600 GT. There must be hundreds!

Answer (score 3):

Creating a 840x525@75Hz custom resolution through the NVIDIA drivers on my screen, I found the image was somewhat blurry. Then I pressed the "menu" button on my screen and it turns out it was actually 840x525 being scaled to 1024x768, which was then displayed in the monitor.

Edit the custom resolution, click the "Timing" button, and choose the standard "GTF". This makes the actual active pixels 840x525 instead of 1024x768 (check bottom).

Comment: This doesn't work with my setup. With the driver I'm currently using, I can choose between "monitor scaling" and "display card scaling". I suppose the former might result in a sharp image, depending on the scaling applied by your monitor. With my monitor, the result is still blurry, unfortunately...